# Is there a python function to 'overlay' only those pixels from a 'Binary Image' that have 'RGB value' Greater than 0 over 'another Binary Image'?

Tags: python-3.x

In these Binary Images, pixels have values equal to either 0 or 255.
I aim to overlay the boundary of one pincode in the binary image of another pincode, so that I can see both the pincode boundaries in one single binary image.

Here are the binary images:

[im_110033](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1BT9hnDrXFiR_Lm2ZRyC1PO96HvFkcZwa)

[im_110027](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pcWsCO8t8suJcWqUOZUaLu7wfaGtGmrM)

This is for an internship Project.

I have written the following code till now:

## Importing libraries

```
import opencv as cv2
import PIL as pil
from PIL import Image
```

## Reading the two images

```
im_110027 = cv2.imread('./Satellite Images/Smoothened Boundaries Satellite Images/im_110027_continous_boundary.png')

im_110033 = cv2.imread('./Satellite Images/Smoothened Boundaries Satellite Images/im_110033_continous_boundary.png')
```

## Adding two images

```
binary_img_add = cv2.add(im_110027, im_110033)
```

## Printing numpy array of binary_img_add

```
print(binary_img_add)
```

The system shows an error:

> name 'binary_img_add' is not defined

Why is this error showing up? and Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any function to do what you want particularly in Python. Given that your image is binary, what you can do is to draw circle over the *pincode* you are talking above the points.

> But the real problem is to make an overlay such that they can be seen.

Because, drawing function would create a third vector in form of RGB which would be not possible to use in your overlay.